# What does active 4h ago mean on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Does it only apply to messenger, or to scrolling as well? How accurate is it?

Answer (score 0):

From [Facebook Help team](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=486660488085628&answer_id=487006414717702&rdrhc):

> When you view your conversations in mobile messages, you'll see how recently your friends interacted with Facebook.
>
> This built-in feature helps give you an idea of how quickly they may respond to any messages you send.

It is actually applies on both when you have Facebook app in your mobile.